# How can I make Emacs back up files right after they are saved?

Tags: backup

I have followed this [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151946/2402577) solution. My goal is to back up files right after I save them.

When I create a new file it is successfully backed up to the given path, but when I close and re-open Emacs the file that I was working on is not backed up or created. Please note that I have created new key bindings for saving and closing.

my setup:

```
(defvar --backup-directory (concat user-emacs-directory "backups_alper"))
(if (not (file-exists-p --backup-directory))
    (make-directory --backup-directory t))

(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,--backup-directory)))
(setq backup-by-copying t)

(setq backup-by-copying t               ; don't clobber symlinks
      version-control t                 ; version numbers for backup files
      delete-old-versions t             ; delete excess backup files silently
      delete-by-moving-to-trash t
      kept-old-versions 6               ; oldest versions to keep when a new numbered backup is made (default: 2)
      kept-new-versions 9               ; newest versions to keep when a new numbered backup is made (default: 2)
      auto-save-default t               ; auto-save every buffer that visits a file
      auto-save-timeout 20              ; number of seconds idle time before auto-save (default: 30)
      auto-save-interval 200            ; number of keystrokes between auto-saves (default: 300)
      )

;; my save:
(defun my-save-all () "My doc-string."
       (interactive)
       (let ((message-log-max nil)
             (inhibit-message t))
         (save-some-buffers t)))

(defun save-all ()
  (interactive)
  (my-save-all)
  (bk-kill-buffers "magit: project")
  (bk-kill-buffers "__init__.py")
  (bk-kill-buffers "*helm"))

(define-key ctl-x-map "\C-s" 'save-all)

;; closing emacs
(defun my-kill-emacs ()
  "save some buffers, then exit unconditionally"
  (interactive)
  (my-save-all)
  ;; (save-some-buffers nil t)
  (save-buffers-kill-terminal))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'my-kill-emacs)
```

Comment: See this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452080/151019

Comment: I have added the answer to the `.emacs` file but it didn't make any affect @mmmmmm

Comment: What did you bind to the new function?

Comment: Could I bind it to my `my-save-all()` function? I try to run `le::save-buffer-force-backup`function but I am not sure where did it save the backup if it does

Comment: The backup is saved according to backup-directory-alist

Comment: Hm I check it out but still the file I am editing on is not backup into that directory :-(, there is only `recentf` and `.emacs` files are saved

Comment: For `(savehist-mode 1)` I keep getting `(void-variable pell-buffer)
  signal(void-variable (pell-buffer))
  savehist-mode(1)` that might be the main cause